# Entity fetched using findById has all fields set to NULL

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Entity fetched using Hibernate has all fields set to NULL. How can I avoid this?
This is my Jpa Repository.

```
@Repository
public interface PolicyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long>{
    Entity findByEntSeqNo(@Param("entSeqNo") long entSeqNo);
}
```

When debugged I can see that fetched data are inside a field name `$$_hibernate_interceptor`

This is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_TABLE")
@Lazy(value = false)
public class Entity extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENT_SEQ_NO")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="entitySeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="entitySeq",sequenceName="\"ENT_SEQ_NO_seq\"", allocationSize=1)
    private long entSeqNo;

    @Column(name = "ENT_CUSTOMER_CODE")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Customer Code is Required.")
    private String entCustomerCode;

    @Column(name = "ENT_CLAS_CODE")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Class Code is Required.")
    private String polcClasCode;

    @Column(name = "ENT_PROD_CODE")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Product Code is Required.")
    private String entProdCode;

    @Column(name = "ENT_BRANCH_CODE")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Branch Code is Required.")
    private String entBranchCode;

    @Column(name = "ENT_YYY_NO")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Yyy Number is Required.")
    private String entYyylNo;

    @Column(name = "ENT_XX_NO")
    private String entXxNo;

    @Column(name = "ENT_XXX_NO")
    private String entXxxNo;

    @Column(name = "ENT_COMMENCEMENT_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date entCommencementDate;

    @Version
    @NotNull(message = "Version is Required.")
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "ENT_EXPIRY_DATE")
    @NotNull(message = "Entity Expiry Date is Required.")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date entExpiryDate;

    @Column(name = "ENT_DELIVERY_MODE")
    private String entDeliveryMode;

    @Column(name = "ENT_COLLECTED_BY")
    private String entCollectedBy;

    @Column(name = "ENT_COLLECTED_USER_NIC")
    private String entCollectedUserNic;

    @Column(name = "ENT_COLLECTED_USER_MOBILE")
    private String entCollectedUserMobile;

    @Column(name = "ENT_COLLECTED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date entCollectedDate;

    @Column(name = "ENT_POSTED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date entPostedDate;

    @Column(name = "ENT_POSTED_REF_NO")
    private String entPostedRefNo;

    @Column(name = "ENT_LANG_CODE")
    private String entLangCode;

    @Column(name = "ENT_PP1_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long entPp1Id;

    @Column(name = "ENT_STATUS")
    private Short entStatus;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENT_PP1_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Pp1 entPp1;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENT_EPP1_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Epp1 entEpp1;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "xxx")
    private Collection<TaskLog> taskLogColletion;
}
```

I'm asking this here since I couldn't find the exact cause for this behavior. All the Jpa operations are working fine and this happens only when I try to pick the details from the database. I also tried `getOne` method and the same problem occurs.

Comment: I do not see any field of The Entity class named polcSeqNo  or PolcPp1_Id ?

Comment: @TinyOS Oh. Sorry, I forgot to rename the fields in the repository class when posting here. Let me fix that.

Comment: @IsuruPathirana What exactly `@Lazy` annotation do you use (from what package)? Could you please also show your `AuditModel` class?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the method : `Entity findByEntSeqNo(@Param("entSeqNo") long entSeqNo);` in your jpa interface because `entSeqNo` is an id of your entity. 
So whene you want to get one Entity by id you can just call `policyRepository.getOne(the value of entSeqNo)` provided by [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-)

Or you can use `policyRepository.findById(the value of entSeqNo)` provided by [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-) whitch is basically a superinterface of JpaRepository

Ps: Do no overwrite these methods in you interface.

Comment: I already tried those. But I'm having the same issue with those methods as well.